# Splitting strings with multiple characters

Tags: c#, string, split

```
if (clientInfo.cf.geo_region != null)
{
    List<string> geoListRegion = clientInfo.cf.geo_region.Split(new string[] { ",", ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    rs_product_hit = rs_product_hit.Where(ph => geoListRegion.Contains(ph.region));
}
```

I want to be able to input either "AMAC,South America" or "AMAC, South America" and split where the comma is placed with/without a space after. Unfortunately, my output is only splitting the comma without the space, giving me the correct output if the input is "AMAC,South America". What could I do to get the same result with or without the space after the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Workaround: changing the order of your splitting strings to `new string[] { ", ", ","}` will resolve the issue. You could also use `string.Trim()` to remove leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you need to do `Trim()`

```
if (clientInfo.cf.geo_region != null)
{
    List<string> geoListRegion = clientInfo.cf.geo_region.Split(new string[] { ",", ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    rs_product_hit = rs_product_hit.Where(ph => geoListRegion.Contains(ph.region.Trim()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. swap the order of your splitting strings as answered by [Bastian Thiede](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839918/splitting-strings-with-multiple-characters/38839957#38839957).
2. Regex. Remove all whitespace after commas using `Regex.Replace(myString, @",\s+", "")`. The benefit of using this method is that it removes any number of spaces succeeding a comma.